# What is the closest equivalent to Go's switch without condition in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, go

In Go, I can use a `switch` without a condition, and instead provide the conditions in the `case` branches, such as:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    t := time.Now()
    switch {
    case t.Hour() < 12:
        fmt.Println("Good morning!")
    case t.Hour() < 17:
        fmt.Println("Good afternoon.")
    default:
        fmt.Println("Good evening.")
    }
}
```

(Taken from https://tour.golang.org/flowcontrol/11)

What I like about this approach is that it is much cleaner than `if-else if-else if-…`. Unfortunately, this construct is not possible in JavaScript.

How could I create something that *looks* like this as closely as possible, using some (weird) language constructs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use virtually the same construct as in Go:

```js
var now = new Date();

switch (true) {
  case now.getHours() < 12:
    console.log('Good morning');
    break;
  case now.getHours() < 17:
    console.log('Good afternoon');
    break;
  default:
    console.log('Good evening');
}
```

Comment: Since when is this syntax possible in JavaScript?

Comment: @GoloRoden Since as long as I can remember.

Comment: @GoloRoden Seems that switch/case was added in ECMAScript 3 (JavaScript 1.5) in 1999. Since it's introduction, it has been possible to use expressions in the case clauses. See spec [here](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-262,%203rd%20edition,%20December%201999.pdf).

Comment: But in practice it has very little reason to use it instead of `if`

Answer (score 1):

You could use [conditions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch#Description) at the case clause.

```js
var a = 2;
switch (true) {  // strict comparison!
    case a < 3:
        console.log(a + ' is smaller than 3');
        break;
}
```

Comment: JavaScript supports this?!?

Answer (score 1):

abusing the language,

```
var now = new Date();
now.getHours() < 12 && console.log('Good morning') ||
now.getHours() < 17 && console.log('Good afternoon') ||
now.getHours() >= 17 && console.log('Good evening')
```